# How to configure .env file of Laravel 5.1 on Heroku?

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5.1

I am new to using heroku with laravel.

I made the deployment successfully, guided by http://goo.gl/cxiljl. But, I don't know how to modify the file `.env` in heroku, to establish data connection to the database.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say that this is your local .env file:

```
EMAIL=foo@example.com
URL=example.com
```

Heroku has a `config:set` command to set a pair `key-value` at config file:

```
$heroku config:set EMAIL=foo@example.com
Adding config vars and restarting myapp... done, v12
EMAIL: foo@example.com
```

To show current config values just type `heroku config`:

```
$heroku config
EMAIL: foo@example.com
```

Finally when you are done setting all var, just move them into the `.env` file one by one:

```
$heroku config:get EMAIL -s  >> .env
```

You can read more about Heroku's commands in the following articles:

- [Configuration and config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)
- [Set up your local environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#set-up-your-local-environment-variables).

Comment: So when deploying to heroku it is required to run this command for every value in our .env file?

Comment: Use the https://github.com/xavdid/heroku-config add-on for the Heroku CLI and entire .env files can be pushed up and pulled down to/from the Heroku apps.